# Проблема со связкой nginx+uwsgi+django

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

Возникла проблема со связкой nginx+uwsgi+django. Вроде всё сделано по инструкции https://habr.com/post/226419/ Тем не менее почему то не могу зайти на страничку с проектом. Вот настройки, может у кого нибудь есть какие нибудь мысли ибо уже всё перепроверил и не могу понять в чём проблема. На этом же сервере лежит сайт*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит «не могу зайти»? Какую-то ошибку пишет? Какую? Логи всех перечисленных программ читали? Фаервол в роутере разрешает зайти? Домен куплен? В домене прописан правильный IP-адрес? Порт 8000 в браузере указывать не забываете?

Comment: Замените изображения текстом.